# RSpec + Capybara scoping returns unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I have two tables: Suggestions and Keywords.
I'm trying to test removal of items from Keywords (which puts it into Suggestions automatically).

Here's my test:

```
it "removes a chosen keyword" do
  page.first(:link, "Add").click
  within(:css, "#keywords") do
    find('li:nth-child(1)').click_link('X')
    expect(page).to have_no_content(item.search.term)
  end
end
```

It results in:

```
  1) New collection Suggestions removes a chosen keyword
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_no_content(item.search.term)
       expected not to find text "Gift for her" in "Keywords\nGift for her X"
     # ./spec/features/collections_spec.rb:60:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/collections_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's the print of the body element:

```
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 mb-4" id="suggestions">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Suggestions</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> 
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="suggestion-list">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Gift for her
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/collections/1/item/choose.1">Add</a><a class="btn btn-primary" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/collections/1/item/destroy.1">X</a><br>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 mb-4" id="keywords">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Keywords</h4>
        <p class="card-text">                     
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="keyword-list">
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my `show.html.erb` file:

```
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 mb-4" id="suggestions">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Suggestions</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> 
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="suggestion-list">
            <% if @suggestions %>
                <% @suggestions.each do |s| %>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <%= Hpricot.uxs s.search.term %>
                  <%= link_to 'Add', collection_item_choose_path(@collection, s),{  method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" } %><%= link_to 'X', collection_item_destroy_path(@collection, s),{  method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" } %><br>
                </li>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 mb-4" id="keywords">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Keywords</h4>
        <p class="card-text">                     
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="keyword-list">
            <% if @keywords %>
              <% @keywords.each do |s| %>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <%= Hpricot.uxs s.search.term %>
                  <%= link_to 'X', collection_item_remove_path(@collection, s),{  method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" } %><br>
                </li>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Seems to me like the scoping is off somehow, although I checked and the link does actually click (you can see it in the puts page.body). Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to be a scoping issue since the reported text is "Keywords\nGift for her X" - whereas if it were seeing the text in the "suggestions" section if would have "Add" text in there too.

More likely is the clicking on the 'X' just isn't getting processed by your app due to an error somewhere.  Check your test.log to see exactly what methods are being called, and whether there are errors.

Additionally you don't mention what driver you're using with Capybara. If you're using a JS capable driver it's possible you don't have `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` set high enough for the hardware you're testing on and/or turbolinks (assuming you have that in your app) is getting involved.  Again, looking at your `test.log` should give a better idea of what's actually happening.  Another to try would be to use `save_and_open_screenshot` to get an image of what the actual page looks like (assuming you're using a driver that supports it)

If you're not using a JS capable driver (ie you're using rack_test) then it's possible you haven't required `capybara/rails` and the method of the links isn't being used. Again, checking `test.log` will show the method (get vs post) being used for each request.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I've been using Selenium and so I set up `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to 30 seconds, still didn't help. Log wasn't throwing any errors at all and for some reason `save_and_open_screenshot` doesn't work on my computer. I solved this with checking that my object count changes instead and it works perfectly. If this helps anyone: `expect { find('li:nth-child(1)').click_link('X') }.to change(item.collection.items.where(chosen: true), :count).by(-1)`

Comment: @MaayanNaveh What do you mean by `save_and_open_screenshot` doesn't work, what error do you get?  Your "solution" isn't really checking the same thing at all (not verifying the UI changes to reflect the models) - and is really a request spec not a feature/system spec.

Comment: completely agree with you there and thank you for the pointers. Here's the error I get when trying to use `save_and_open_screenshot`:  `Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
       Capybara::Driver::Base#save_screenshot`

Comment: @MaayanNaveh that means you’re not using The selenium driver for that test. You’re using the rack_test driver which doesn’t support JS.  If you expected it to be run with Selenium then check you have the `js: true` metadata correctly on the test, (or have set `default_driver` correctly)

Comment: Thank you so much for solving that one too! I really really appreciate it!

Comment: @MaayanNaveh You're welcome - don't forget to accept the answer and mark the question as answered (the checkmark) if it's solved for you